# ng2-completer get selectedObject

Tags: angular

How can I get originalObject in selected event?

for example in this code I want use value field but search in colors!

```
protected searchData = [
{ color: 'red', value: '#f00' },
{ color: 'green', value: '#0f0' },
{ color: 'blue', value: '#00f' },
{ color: 'cyan', value: '#0ff' },
{ color: 'magenta', value: '#f0f' },
{ color: 'yellow', value: '#ff0' },
{ color: 'black', value: '#0' }
];

constructor(private completerService: CompleterService) {
  this.dataService = completerService.local(this.searchData, 'color','color');
}
```

and this is my template:

```
<ng2-completer [(ngModel)]="searchStr" [datasource]="dataService" 
[minSearchLength]="0">
```

Thanks.

Comment: I use this and works for me:

(selected)="onItemSelect($event)"

and

onItemSelect(selected:CompleterItem){
if(selected)
this.selectedItem = selected.originalObject._id;
}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<ng2-completer name="searchStr" [(ngModel)]="model.searchStr" [datasource]="dataService" [minSearchLength]="0" (selected)="onItemSelect($event)" #searchStr="ngModel"></ng2-completer>


export class .....Component{
 model:any={};
 ... 
 ... ..
 ...
onItemSelect(selected:CompleterItem){

  if(selected)
      this.model.searchStr = selected.originalObject.value;
  }
}
}
```